# WPF & MVVM: Get values from textboxes and send it to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, delegatecommand

I'm trying to get the value of two Texboxes (I'm simulating a login window) when I press a button. The command assigned in the button fires correctly, but I don't know how to get the value of the textboxes to do the "login".

This is my ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{   
    public LoginViewModel()
    {

    }

    private DelegateCommand loginCommand;
    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loginCommand == null)
                loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(LoginExecuted),
                               new Func<bool>(LoginCanExecute));
                return loginCommand;
            }
        } 

    public bool LoginCanExecute()
    {
        //Basic strings validation...
        return true;
    }
    public void LoginExecuted()
    {
        //Do the validation with the Database.
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OK");
    } 
}
```

This is the view:

```
 <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource LoginViewModel}">

            <TextBox x:Name="LoginTxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="34,62,0,0" Width="154" />
            <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordTxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="34,104,0,0" Width="154"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAccept"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="34,153,0,0" 
            Width="108" 
            Content="{DynamicResource acceptBtn}" Height="31" BorderThickness="3"
            Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

If somebody can help...I'll be infinitely grateful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Typically, you'd bind the `TextBox.Text` properties to properties on your ViewModel.  This way, the values are stored within the ViewModel, not the View, and there is no "getting" of the values required.

```
class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ 
    //...
    private string userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return this.userName; }
        set 
        {
           // Implement with property changed handling for INotifyPropertyChanged
           if (!string.Equals(this.userName, value))
           {
               this.userName = value;
               this.RaisePropertyChanged(); // Method to raise the PropertyChanged event in your BaseViewModel class...
           }
        } 
    }

    // Same for Password...
```

Then, in your XAML, you'd do something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="34,62,0,0" Width="154" />
<PasswordBox Text="{Binding Password}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="34,104,0,0" Width="154"/>
```

At this point, the `LoginCommand` can use the local properties directly.

Comment: Although its a old post, but how do i achieve the same functionality if i need to pass multiple email addresses in the Text Box field? In the textBox Suppose I write like this "abcd@gmail.com, defg@yahoo.com,test@gmail.com" then how do i bind that to viewmodel

Comment: @Debhere You'd need to split the emails using string.Split or similar to extract them in the VM.